# JSContext onload trigger

Tags: swift, javascriptcore

I need to rewrite that bunch of code from Objective-c to swift:

```
    JSContext *jsContext = [webView valueForKeyPath:@"documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext"];
jsContext[@"loaded"] = ^{
    NSLog(@"Content Loaded!");
};
```

The question is about getting context when webView is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for swift:

```
 if let jsContext = svtwebView?.value(forKeyPath: "documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext") as? JSContext {
                let loaded: @convention(block) () -> Void = {
                    print("Loaded:")
                }
                jsContext.setObject(loaded, forKeyedSubscript: "loaded" as NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol)
                jsContext.evaluateScript("loaded")
            }
```